# In Laravel 5 how do I implement an App::before() filter?

Tags: routes, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

In Laravel 4.2 I had this before filter that set the Eloquent model and table based on the URL (admin.example.com vs example.com)

Here is my filter code:

```
App::before(function($request)
{       
  // Check if we are using the admin URL
  $host = $request->getHost();
  $parts = explode('.', $host);
  if ($parts[0] == 'admin')
  {
    // Set the config for user info (not sponsor)
    Config::set('auth.model', 'Admin');
    Config::set('auth.table', 'admins');
  }
});
```

I tried creating middleware for this in laravel 5 and have this code:

```
class AdminOrSponsor implements Middleware {

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {   
    $host = $request->getHost();
    $parts = explode('.', $host);
    if ($parts[0] == 'admin'){
        Config::set('auth.model', 'Admin');
        Config::set('auth.table', 'admins');
    }

    return $next($request);
  }

}
```

In my routes.php file I am setting the controller that is called based on the auth.model setting like this:

```
Route::get('/auth/login', Config::get('auth.model') . 'Controller@getLogin');
Route::post('/auth/login', Config::get('auth.model') . 'Controller@postLogin');
Route::get('/auth/logout', Config::get('auth.model') . 'Controller@getLogout');
```

What I found is that the routes are all read prior to the middleware so the change I am trying to make through Config::set() isn't happening.  I am only getting the value that is set in the auth.php config file.

What am I doing wrong and how should I do this in Laravel 5?

Comment: I haven't tested this myself but did you try simply adding your before filter to the boot() method of app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php? Check the "Route Filters" section of the upgrade guide here: [Upgrading To 5.0 From 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0)

Comment: I added my filter to the RouteServiceProvider and got it to work.  Thanks for the tip.  IT isn't a great solution as I need access to Request::getHost() and Request isn't available here.  I implemented a temporary use of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to get what I need.  Hoping somebody can find a more appropriate way to do this.

Comment: in order to have access to Request::getHost(), you just need to add "use Illuminate\Http\Request;" at the top, before class.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to load different routes depending on the client's hostname.

I understand your solution, but it is sort of a hack and you'll run into trouble when you want to unit test this, if you can even get it to work. The config is loaded before the routes, so setting routes based on the request is impossible, unless you rely on $_SERVER (which also breaks unittests).

I would do the following:

1. Create the routes as such:

   ```
   Route::get('/auth/login', 'AuthController@getLogin');
   Route::get('/auth/login/admin', 'AdminsController@getLogin');
   Route::get('/auth/login/sponsors', 'SponsorsController@getLogin');
   ```
2. Create a middleware to prevent access to the AdminsController by the sponsors, and vice-versa.
3. Inside the AuthController, perform a redirect from `auth/login` to either admins or sponsors, depending on the host.

Then you are only using "standard" laravel features, and you can be sure that it doesn't cause any strange side-effects.