# Using \App::before() in RouteServiceProvider in Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Migrating from Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 5.0. I moved `\App::before(function($request)` from my L4.2 filters.php to the L5.0's RouteServiceProvider.php’s `boot()` method, but I’m getting a

`FatalErrorException in Facade.php line 210: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::before()`

error thrown from it. What am I doing wrong?

I haven’t found anything that says this shouldn’t work; [an SO question/answer says that it worked for another guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846443/in-laravel-5-how-do-i-implement-an-appbefore-filter), so I'm not sure where my code is different. I've tried include `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;` and just `\App::before`, to no avail.

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    public function boot(Router $router)
    {

        App::before(function($request)
        {
            //My before code
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#defining-middleware). In your case you can create a new middleware using the artisan commands. Use the following command for help:

```
php artisan help make:middleware
```

Then [register](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#registering-middleware) your middleware in App\Http\Kernel.php

Finally use [Route Group Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-middleware) or [Controller Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#controller-middleware) for protection.

Comment: Great, there is even a section in the Middleware docs about Before/After. http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware